# Why does QTranslator (PyQt5) refuse to work after Update to 5.10?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I have a GUI that makes use of `PyQt5` standard dialogs and the following script kept translating the buttons. This worked fine until the update from `5.9.2` to `5.10` was released. Suddenly, the translator stopped doing its job without any changes in the script.

```
app = QApplication(sys.argv)

translator = QTranslator(app)
locale = QLocale.system().name()
path = QLibraryInfo.location(QLibraryInfo.TranslationsPath)

translator.load('qt_%s' % locale, path)
app.installTranslator(translator)
```

When having a closer look at what might have happened, I discovered that the translator fails to load and thus it cannot be installed, although there is a locale and the according .qm file (`'de_AT'` and `qt_de.qm`). Even when trimming the string down to `'de'` and experimenting with `.qm` in the string, the translation did not work.
This is what I get when printing the steps from above:

```
path  C:/ProgramData/Anaconda3/lib/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt/translations
locale  de_AT
load  False
install  False
```

Any suggestions why the translator does not work in version `5.10` for me any longer?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: something got changed, but I don't know the details, just recently read this: [New in Qt 5.10: Dynamic Language Change in QML](http://www.embeddeduse.com/2017/11/12/new-in-qt-5-10-dynamic-language-change-in-qml/)

Comment: Did you try regenerating the .qm files since updating?

Comment: I found that my qt_de.qm file has only 1KB, this has been the problem! Thanks! Problem solved!